# How to check if cursor is on an empty line inside textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, line-breaks

How do I check if the cursor is on an empty line inside a textarea?

I don't care about word wrapping. I care about lines that were created by hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
$('textarea').on("change keyup", function() {
  if (cursor is on an empty line or the the line has just spaces) {
    console.log("empty");
  } else {
    console.log("has stuff");
  }
});
```

For example:

> This would log "has stuff"
>
> The line above would log "empty" and this line would log "has stuff"

Comment: As i know javascript it is not possible

Comment: An empty line can be due to word-wrapping as well as one that was generated by a CR/LF. Which do you care about?

Comment: The only approach I can think of (count the characters) depends on the browser using a monospace font inside the textarea, which can't be guaranteed anymore.

Comment: @Diodeus I care about any linebreak that takes the cursor to a blank line that has nothing in it or just whitespace.

Comment: @Diodeus I don't care about word wrapping.

Comment: Look at the ASCII value of the character before the cursor, if it's 10 or 13, you have a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following *should* work, but won't in older versions of IE.

```
// on(..., function() {
if( this.value.substr(0,this.selectionStart).match(/(?:^|\r?\n\s*)$/)
 && this.value.substr(this.selectionStart).match(/^(?:\s*\r?\n|$)/)) {
    console.log("empty");
}
```

EDIT search now explicitly looks for a newline, with further whitespace optional.

Comment: What does `this` refer to here, the value of the textarea?

Comment: It refers to the element on which the event is bound. In this case, the textarea itself.

Comment: Actually, scratch that. If the textarea has any text at all it wont work :/

Comment: That's because you changed my code... But you're right about the first and last line stuff. I've edited my answer and [updated your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5uZjV/1/)

Comment: That's great thanks. There is only one issue. If you start a line, for example, `hello   `, then add a space or more, the console will log `empty`. If the line has any text at all, I want it to log `has stuff`. Is that not possible? I tried tweaking the regex, but no luck.

Comment: Great, thank you. The first `substr()` looks at the start and end of line, right? What's the second `substr()` for? The one after the `&&`.

Comment: The first `substr` gets everything before the cursor, and the regex tests to ensure that it ends with a newline (ie. there is no text before the cursor or a newline). The second `substr` gets everything after the cursor, and does the same kind of check.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be:

```
function is_cursor_on_empty_line(textarea)
{
    // line where cursor is now
    var line_number = textarea.value.substr(0, textarea.selectionStart).split("\n").length;
    
    // split all lines of the textarea
    var lines = textarea.value.split("\n");

    // current line is empty or not
    return (lines[line_number-1] == '');
}
```

Example usage with Jquery:

```
var textarea = $('textarea');

if (is_cursor_on_empty_line(textarea[0]))
{
   // ...
}
```