# How to check cursor is on newline or not in ckeditor 4.x

Tags: ckeditor

I want to check cursor position that it is on new line or not ? I am using ckeditor 4.4 version.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20980870/how-to-check-if-cursor-is-on-an-empty-line-inside-textarea

Comment: How is it possible to focus the cursor on a newline? Sounds impossible to me. Do you mean an empty paragraph?